# Postman test fails while parsing the xml soap response

Tags: soap, postman

I am using POSTMAN to send a SOAP request and below is my `soapenv` response received. I would like to test for the below value received in my postman test, but the post man test fails, could someone advise on what to do here ?

`LicStatus`

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas.general.com.au:api:other">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:urn="urn:schemas.general.com.au:api:other" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <header xmlns:urn="urn:schemas.general.com.au:api:other" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
            <msg-id>005056B9-3921-A1E9-A327-64509F7362DC</msg-id>
            <messageoptions noreply="true"/>
        </header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getSupplierDataResponse xmlns:urn="urn:schemas.general.com.au:api:other" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:schemas.general.com.au:api:other" xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.cordys.com/default_005056B9-5D92-A1E9-904D-128C719CE2DD" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.cordys.com/casemanagement/1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.XXTGGHG.org/2004/07/STRD.Models" xmlns:ns3="urn:schemas.general.com.au:canonical:technical:v1" xmlns:ns2="urn:schemas.general.com.au:api:other" xmlns:bpm="http://schemas.cordys.com/default" xmlns:sm="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" xmlns:instance="http://schemas.cordys.com/bpm/instance/1.0">
            <CustomerData>
                <DateLicenceExpires>28/01/2020</DateLicenceExpires>
                <Demonstration_Method>Certification</Demonstration_Method>
                <AuditLastAuditDate>05/03/2018</AuditLastAuditDate>
                <AuditOutcome>Non Compliance</AuditOutcome>
                <HeadOfficeRegion/>
                <ScopeOfLicencing>YES</ScopeOfLicencing>
                <LicStatus>Licensed</LicStatus>   
            </CustomerData>
            <OperationResult xmlns="urn:schemas.general.com.au:canonical:technical:v1">
                <Status>00</Status>
                <StatusMessage>Success</StatusMessage>
            </OperationResult>
        </getSupplierDataResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the post man test:

```
pm.test('Verify the LicStatus', function() {
var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
pm.expect(responseJson.results[0].LicStatus).to.eql("Licensed");

})
```

Comment: Where are you getting `results[0]` from? I would have thought, from looking at the response, that `responseJson.CustomerData.LicStatus` would be closer to what you need. What do you see when you do `console.log('responseJson')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
pm.test('Verify the LicStatus', function() {
    var xmlTree = xml2Json(responseBody);
    var licenseStatus = xmlTree['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'].getSupplierDataResponse.CustomerData.LicStatus;

    pm.expect(licenseStatus).to.eql("Licensed");
})
```